# How to check an element clicked or not - selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to check click functionality by using selenium. Here I'm able to click particular element through test case, but for my test case perspective I need to return whether element clicked or not. If the click happens it should return true otherwise need to return false.
This is how I'm doing click operation.

```js
  find(By.xpath("elementpath")).click();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a listener to the element and setAttribute as part of javascript. Check the attribute once you click on the element.

Below code will an alert when you click on the element. (implemented in Python- execute_script = javascript execution)

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
driver.execute_script("var ele = arguments[0];ele.addEventListener('click', function() {ele.setAttribute('automationTrack','true');});",element)
element.click()
# now check the onclick attribute
print(element.get_attribute("automationTrack"))
```

output:

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you man. This method is really awesome. You helped me a lot with this. In case anyone also wants to know if the current page has changed due to the just made click() -> then check if after running "element.get_attribute("automationTrack")" the Exception StaleElementReferenceException is thrown or not. If is thrown then the element got changed, which means that the page has changed too.

Answer (score 2):

*Please have a look at below method which would be more reliable and give you desired outcome as it would click only when element becomes clickable & tells whether it was clicked or not.*

```
public static boolean isClicked(WebElement element)
{ 
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        element.click();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Call this method in your class like - boolean bst = className.isClicked(elementRef);*

Comment: this will not work if the button is always clickable. any idea how to implement a solution if the button is always clickable (preferably in python)?

Comment: I don't understand the demur you gave here @oldboy. What would be the problem with the button always being clickable and that you wanted to solve? If you wanted to wait with the click out of some other reason than clickability, then what were you waiting for?

Comment: @MiB i cant remember exactly why i wrote that, but im guessing what i meant is something like if the `disabled` attribute is active on the HTML element

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try-catch block do that for you.

```
try{
   find(By.xpath("elementpath")).click();
}catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
   return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer from @supputuri, I came up with this Java solution testing with Junit, though the main changes I needed to do was in the JS.

```
String script = "let clicked = false;"
    + "var btn = arguments[0];"
    + "btn.addEventListener('click', () => {"
    + "window.clicked = true;"//without window failed
    + "});"
```

I choose an external variable for storing the click result as my button was about to disappear from the dom post-click. I don't think you can request data belonging to a non-existing element. Execute the JS with the previously created JavascriptExecutor (here referred to as "js" ) in order to actually add the listener:

```
js.executeScript(script, myButton);
```

and do the click and retrieve the value:

```
myButton.click();
Boolean clicking = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return clicked;");
assertTrue(clicking);
```